# Save password and username issue in firefox at login time[autofilled]

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Hi while login i used remember password checkbox of firefox.
After login the remembered email and password is autofilled in the text boxes of names with names given as textfield as `value=mobileNumber` and `value=pass`.

Here in above `textField`, `mobileNumber` is stored with `emailId` and `pass` is stored with `password`, which is entered at the time of login.

```
      //mobile text field
      <input id="ember1245" class="ember-view ember-text-field mobile"   type="text">

    //password textfield
    <input id="ember1247" class="ember-view ember-text-field placeholder" placeholder="New Password" type="password">
```

I am using ember and Handlebar templates

This is happening only in the FireFox But all other Browsers works fine

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: You want to have such a feature? (or) you would like to get rid of the default browser behaviour?

Comment: you want to say that you are facing the issue with firefox browser only?

Comment: yes i m facing in firefox and i want get rid of this browser behaviour

Comment: its occurs only when mobile number is not filed in text box ( if not entered mobile number)means if null value is there than only its get                                          {{input type="text" class="mobile" autocomplete="off" value=mobileNumber }} like this if u take value equel to anything it takes email id only that to value is null if any other value (if entered mobile number and save it display mobile number if not email id) is there it display that value

Comment: please see the link and screen shot same issues i m geting in fierfox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379091/how-can-i-avoid-browser-prepopulating-fields-in-my-registration-form

Comment: i got solution for this problem but i take input type is string means

Comment: i got solution for this problem but i take input type as string like <input type="string" value= emaill/> its working fine , i search the html5 i am not get any  input type="string" ,i want no this the correct way or not,