# input type="string" is it correct input type?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Currently I am having problem in firefox browser if I use: its      automatically displaying the value the password and email when saving the password in firefox.

```
<input type="text" value= email/>
<input type="text" value= mobilenumber/>
```

I solved the problem by using it as:

```
<input type="string" value= email/>
<input type="string" value= mobilenumber/>
```

Now I need a source which can tell like there is an `input type= "string"`.

So please can anyone help me finding the link to source.

Comment: please look into this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026909/save-password-and-username-issue-in-firefox-at-login-timeautofilled

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.html

Comment: @Andreas the link is broken!

Comment: Living Standard: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element

Answer (score 1):

To hide data being typed in input fields use the `password` type:

```
<input type="password" name="pword" />
```

*The field will fill with `*` instead of the typed data.*

If the issue is that data is saved in the browser and is automatically filled in, you can prevent this by disabling `autocomplete`:

```
<input type="text" name="info" autocomplete="off" />
```

Beware: Chrome may ignore this attribute in some scenarios.
See this for more information [stackoverflow.com/.../chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off)

---

`string` is not a valid type, so the field will default to the `text` type.

Using this type will work since it defaults to text, and might make the browser not use autcomplete since the fields don't match the saved input data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no input type called *string*. In the comments to your question there are some URLs that show proof. Usually, at least with my experience, inputs with undefined types are usually *text* boxes.

Comment: than how to solve this problem , if i save the password in fierfox

Comment: while login i used remember password checkbox of firefox. After login the remembered email and password is autofilled in the text boxes of names with names given as textfield as value=mobileNumber and value=pass.

Here in above textField, mobileNumber is stored with emailId and pass is stored with password, which is entered at the time of login.