# HTML form - Don't load saved login into new user form

Tags: html

I have a management area where the admins can create new users for the site. 
 The "New User" form currently loads the admin's login when the admin saves their login to their browser.  I already have `autocomplete` turned off on the fields in the "New User" form. 
 Is there a way to also not load the admin's saved email and password without changing the field names in the form?

**EDIT**

I guess this is not clear, so I will explain more.

On my input fields for the email address and password, I have the input field attribute `autocomplete` set to `off`.

However, the browser will still load the logged-in user's saved email and password in to the fields.  This is the part I need to stop from happening.

Comment: are you referring to the browser's autocomplete or the form's autocomplete? I believe the two are different.

Comment: @Wold Yes, they are 2 different things.  I have the form's autocomplete turned off.  Now I need to turn off the browser's ability to auto-populate the username/password to the form.

Comment: Referring to `<form autocomplete="on|off">`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag) or [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form?rq=1)

Comment: @AniMenon It depends on what you mean.  Yes, if you mean is that what I currently have (except I have it on individual form fields).  But I also want to stop the browser from loading the saved login for the website.

Comment: @James I hope you got the answers from the duplicates.

Comment: @AniMenon No, I did not.  This is not a duplicate question, but thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: Well often times, browsers have their own system of logging the client's username/password that is independent  of any of the webpage's code. In that case, it is impossible to stop it from autoloading without the client changing his browser settings himself.

Comment: @Wold Thank you for the comment.  I actually just seen a similar post saying the same thing as I continue to google this issue.  I do see a possible fix I am going to try real quick that basically just tricks the browser into not knowing it's the login...

Comment: @Wold In case you are curious, check the "answer" I just posted.  Seems to work, but is basically just a hack job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I avoid browser prepopulating fields in my registration form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379091/how-can-i-avoid-browser-prepopulating-fields-in-my-registration-form)

Comment: @BSMP Wow, good catch.  What gave it away?  The fact that I stated that's where I found my answer?...  hahahah ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to another post at [How can I avoid browser prepopulating fields in my registration form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379091/how-can-i-avoid-browser-prepopulating-fields-in-my-registration-form) I was able to fix this.  At least, to find a work-around.  The trick was to put invisible `text` and `password` type inputs between my actual email and password inputs.  The browser uses the invisible inputs instead and leaves my actual inputs alone.

Comment: ah yes, I remember having to deal with this a while back. It is kind of a hacky solution, but if it works, it works.